# Converting each method in Jquery to Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, for-loop, each

```
$.each(data.features[i].properties, function(key, val){
  items[i][j].push(val);
}
```

I'm using this each method in my code with the function which has key and val as the parameters of the function.
I want to convert this to a for loop in TypeScript, but I can't figure out how to get the key and val parameters as well.

```
var heads = [];
var items:any[] = [];
$.each( data.features[0].properties, function( key, val ) { 
  heads.push(key);
});
for(let i=0; i<data.features.length; i++){
  //$.each(data.features[i].properties, function(key, val)
  for(let j=0; j<data.features[i].properties.length; j++){
    items[i][j].push(val);
  }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to implement.

I'm getting a geoJSON file in data. It has several features and each feature has some properties which I want to push in the array.

Comment: what is `j` here and mention in quetion what is the shape of `data.features[i].properties`

Comment: `data.features[i].properties.reduce((prev , {key, val}) => {
  return prev[i][j].push(val);
}, items);`  will work

Comment: @Teemu Hi, sorry my bad. I've edited the question can you please check again?

Comment: @diEcho I have updated the question, can you please check again